# Are turbofans compensated for gyro effect?

Tags: jet-engine, engine-design

In a multi-spool design is the gyro effect canceled or mitigated by having the two or more spools spinning in different directions?

Comment: Related: [Why does the LP compressor rotate in the opposite direction of the HP compressor?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/why-does-the-lp-compressor-rotate-in-the-opposite-direction-of-the-hp-compressor) and [Why are contra-rotating jet engines so rare?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31613/why-are-contra-rotating-jet-engines-so-rare)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few counter rotating turbo fans, such as the GEnx. But the majority are co rotating.